# I'm getting a TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable

Tags: python

I got an error message from my code which says `TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable`. After doing some research, I understand what it means, but I can't understand why there is a problem.

I narrowed the problem down to this code:

```
def calcNextPos(models, xcel): # and other irrelevant parameters
    for i in range(len(models)):
        for j in range(3):
            a = xcel[i[j]]*0.5*dt*dt
            # More code after this...
```

I verified that `xcel` is a list of lists of integers when the function is called, and the indexes should not be out of bounds.

What is going wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xcel` is a two-dimensional list. The correct syntax to access the `j`th element of the `i`th sub-list is `xcel[i][j]`, not `xcel[i[j]]`. The latter attempts to get the `j`th element of the integer `i`, which leads to the error described.

Answer (score -1):

In the code `for i in range(len(models)):`, `i` is an integer. That makes a loop for values of `i` between `0` and `a` less than the length of `models`.

In the next two lines of the code, `i[j]` is used to access an array element, which doesn't work. Did you perhaps mean `models[j]` instead of `i[j]`, like so?

```
for i in range(len(models)):
    for j in range(3):
        a = xcel[models[j]]*0.5*dt*dt
        # More code after this...
```