# I'm getting a TypeError. How do I fix it?

Tags: python, debugging, typeerror

I commonly get uncaught exceptions (errors) from my Python code that are described as `TypeError`s. After considerable experimentation and research, I was able to collect the following examples (and minor variations):

```
TypeError: func() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
TypeError: func() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
TypeError: func() got an unexpected keyword argument 'arg'
TypeError: func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'
TypeError: func() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'arg'
TypeError: func() got multiple values for argument 'arg'
TypeError: MyClass() takes no arguments
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
TypeError: string indices must be integers
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'str'
TypeError: descriptor 'to_bytes' for 'int' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I have also seen custom messages when trying to use a function, method or class from a library.

What is a `TypeError`? What do messages like this mean? How can I understand and fix the problem?

---

<sub>If your question was closed as a duplicate of this, please carefully read and follow the advice here, and try to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the code and [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) any remaining problem before asking again. Stack Overflow is not a debugging service.</sub>

<sub>A valid, non-duplicate question about a `TypeError` will ask why a [specific, minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) causes a `TypeError`, and explain what you expected to happen instead and why.</sub>

Comment: This question is intended as an artificial canonical duplicate to close simple questions about `TypeError`s. Please do not try to close it as a duplicate of something else; the goal here is to describe `TypeError` generally enough to encompass common problems, while still asking the same *question* about all of them. See [I'm getting an IndentationError. How do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722) for precedent. This answer also exists at least partially to help find more specific canonicals for particular causes of `TypeError`.

Comment: I think "NoneType" errors are common enough that they should get their own unique canonical treatment.

Comment: @MarkRansom I intended this one to be about the process of reading and understanding the error message. `NoneType` is a type, not an error; and there are multiple `TypeError`s that could potentially mention it (not to mention `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'foo'`, which IMX is more common than any of those). However, you should of course feel free to draft your own canonicals of that sort.

Answer (score 12):

## What is a `TypeError`?

It means exactly what it sounds like: there is an `Error` that is caused by the `Type` of one or more of the values in the code.

### ... but what is a "type"?

In a Python program, every object has a *type*. By "object" (equivalently in Python, "value") we mean something that can be given a *name* in the source code. Most names are simple variables: if we write `x = 1`, then `1` is an object, it has a name `x`, and its type is `int` - the type itself has a name.

"Type" means more or less what it sounds like: it tells you *what kind of thing* something else is. `1`, `2` and `3` are all integers; they have the same type, `int`. You can think of it as representing *the concept of* an integer.

Not every type has a built-in name. For example, functions are objects (most other languages don't work this way!), and they have a type, but we can't directly refer to that type by name in our code.

Every type *does* have a representation as an object, however, whether it's named or not. You can [use the built-in `type`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402504) to get such a "type object":

```
>>> type(1) # the result from this...
<class 'int'>
>>> int # is the same:
<class 'int'>
>>> type(int) # We can look a bit deeper:
<class 'type'>
>>> def func():
...     pass
>>> type(func) # and get types that aren't named:
<class 'function'>
>>> type(type) # and there's this special case:
<class 'type'>
```

Notably, the type of `type` *is `type` itself*.

You may notice that Python (3.x) displays these type objects with the word `class`. This is a useful reminder: when you create a `class`, you are *defining a new type of data*. That is the purpose of classes.

### What do messages like this mean?

We can break the examples down into a few categories:

```
TypeError: func() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
TypeError: func() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
TypeError: func() got an unexpected keyword argument 'arg'
TypeError: func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'
TypeError: func() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'arg'
TypeError: func() got multiple values for argument 'arg'
TypeError: MyClass() takes no arguments
```

These exceptions are telling you that the arguments (the things you put between the `()`) for calling `func` (or creating an instance of `MyClass`) are wrong. Either there are too many, not enough, or they are not properly labelled.

This is admittedly a little confusing. We're trying to call a function, and the thing we're calling is a function - so the type does actually match. The identified problem is with the *number of* arguments. However, Python reports this as a `TypeError` rather than a `ValueError`. This might be in order to look more familiar to programmers from other languages such as C++, where "types" are checked at compile time and can be very complex - such that functions that accept different types or numbers of arguments, are themselves considered to have different types.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

These exceptions are telling you that the left-hand side and right-hand side of an *operator* (a symbol like `+` or `>` or `^`, used to *compute a result*) [don't make sense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39432551). For example, trying to divide or subtract strings, or [repeat a string a non-integer number of times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485789), or (in 3.x) [compare strings to numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886881). As a special case, you can use `+` between two strings (or lists, or tuples), but it doesn't "add" them in a mathematical sense. If you try to use `+` between an integer and a string, the error message will be different depending on the order.

```
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

These ones are a bit tricky. The `%` operator is used to get the *modulus* (remainder when dividing numbers), but it can also be used to format strings by replacing some placeholders. (This is an outdated system that's [hard to get right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568627) and [has weird special cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455602/); in new code, please use f-strings or the `.format` method.)

An error occurs because the placeholders in the string on the left-hand side don't match up with what's on the right-hand side. In the second case, it's likely that you actually wanted to calculate a modulus, so the left-hand side should be a number (most likely an integer) instead. It's debatable whether these should be `ValueError`s instead, since it could be that the *contents* of the string are wrong. However, Python cannot read your mind.

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

This is also a problem with an operator, this time the `[]` operator (used for indexing into a list, slicing a list, or looking up a key in a dictionary). A string makes sense inside the `[]` if we are looking up a key in a dictionary that has strings as keys; but we cannot index into a list with it.

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'str'
```

These mean that [something wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836795) was passed to a built-in function (or another callable, such as a type). Functions that you get from a library may raise their own `TypeError`s with custom messages. The message should be pretty straightforward.

```
TypeError: descriptor 'to_bytes' for 'int' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object
```

This one is very unusual, and most people who ask this question would never run into it ([except maybe with the `datetime` standard library module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66431493)). It happens because of trying to use a method as if it were a function, but giving it the wrong type of thing for `self`: for example, `int.to_bytes('1')`. The code is wrong because `'1'` is a string, and strings don't support `.to_bytes`. Python will not convert the string to integer; and it cannot give an `AttributeError` instead because `to_bytes` was looked up *in the class*, not on the string.

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

These mean exactly what they sound like. ["iterable" means "able to be iterated"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952464/); i.e., checked repeatedly to get separate values. This happens in `for` loops, comprehensions and when trying to convert to list etc. The "unpack" variation of the message results from trying to [use unpacking syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451194) on the non-iterable.

["callable" means "able to be called"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/); to "call" something is to write `()` after it (possibly with arguments between the `()`). Code like `1('test')` doesn't make sense because `1` isn't a function (or a type).

["subscriptable" means "able to be subscripted"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/); here, "subscripting" means either using slice syntax (`x[1:2:3]`), or indexing or looking for a key (`x['test']`). We can only do this with *sequences* (like `list`s or `str`ings) and *mappings* (like `dict`s).

Answer (score 6):

## How can I understand and fix the problem?

First, look at the traceback to see *where in the code* the error occurs. If it's in a library, work backwards to the point where your code uses the library. Then read the error message carefully, and compare it to the code, to figure out *what* causes the complaint. Finally, think carefully: is the *operation* wrong, or the *values*?

### Examples

(TODO)

### Some non-obvious things

#### Reusing names

Did you perhaps [reassign the name of a built-in callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039605/), such as `str` or `input` or `list`? Did you try to [reuse a name for two different things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29101836) (for example, a function and some global data that it uses)?

Names in Python can only refer to one thing at a time. If you use, say, `list` as a variable name, then it isn't also the name of "the abstract concept of a list" any more, so you can't use it to create more lists (which includes converting other things to lists). If you create a global variable `months` with a list of strings, and then write a function `months`, the function replaces the list, and the function's code can't look up the list. This can easily happen accidentally [when using `from some_module import *` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046656).

Similarly, if you try to make a class that [uses the same name for an method as for a data attribute of the instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949064), that will cause the same problem. (There's also a [tricky special case with `@staticmethod`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718187)).

#### Processing lists

Sometimes people expect to be able to use a list like a Numpy array, and "broadcast" an [operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534855) or a [function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953127/) to each element of the list. That doesn't work. [Use a list comprehension instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082410/).

#### Handling `None`

Consider whether you [need to handle `None` as a special case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930188). But try to avoid getting into that situation in the first place; "special cases aren't special enough to break the rules", as they say.

#### Trying to use a library (including a standard library)

If something doesn't work like you'd expect (for example, trying to [subtract `datetime.time`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259882) or [serialize an instance of a user-defined class as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895)) - rather than trying to treat the problem as a debugging question, search for solutions for *what you want that part of the code to do*.

#### If the error mentions a 'str' type and you thought it should be a number

Did you get it from the `input` function? That gives you a `str`, even if it *looks like* a number. Please see [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/).

#### If the error mentions a 'function' type or 'type' type

Did you forget to call the function, or create an instance of a class?

---

### Error messages about wrong arguments

The error message will tell you the name of the function; so look at the part of the line that calls that function, and check the arguments. Is there a correct number of positional arguments? Is there a keyword argument that must be provided, and is missing? Is there a keyword argument that *shouldn't* be provided? Is there a positional argument that is also provided by keyword?

If you are writing a method for a class, [remember to allow for `self`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944657). It [is necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/) for instance methods. If you are calling a method, keep in mind that `self` will be counted as an argument (both for the amount "required" and the amount "given").

A common beginner error is attempting to use a method (which
isn't a `classmethod`) from a class without instantiating it. You'd do something like

```py
value = MyClass.method(things)
```

where you should be doing something like

```py
instance = MyCLass()
value = instance.method(things)
```

which (obscurely) passes `instance` as the first (`self`) argument to `method`, and `things` as the second argument.

If you are using a callback that takes arguments from an indirect source, [check the source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116721).

If you are trying to create an instance of your own class, and get an `TypeError` from `__init__`, [make sure that you actually wrote an `__init__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72482298/).

If you don't know what the arguments should be, **check the documentation**. If the arguments make sense, maybe the *function* is wrong - make sure you didn't confuse it for another one in the same library.

### Error messages about operand types

Make sure the operator is correct for what you want the code to do (for example: `^` [is not exponentiation; you want `**`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34258537)), and then check the operand types.

In most cases, it will be appropriate to convert the type - but think carefully. Make sure the operation will make sense with the new types. For example, if the code is `l + 'second'`, and `l` is a `list` that currently contains `['first']`, chances are good we don't want to concatenate strings, but instead create a modified list that also has `'second'` as an element. So actually we wanted to ["add" another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902980): `l + ['second']`.

If `string indices must be integers`, it could be that the string being indexed [is JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839195/) or something of that sort, which should have been parsed already to create a dictionary (possibly with nested lists and dictionaries).

If `list indices must be integers or slices`, it's likely that the problem is with the `list`, rather than the index. If you expected the `list` to be a `dict`, check whether it *contains* a `dict` - especially if it contains exactly one element, which is a `dict`. Then check if that's the `dict` that should actually be looked into. If so, the solution is easy: simply add another level of indexing, in order to grab that `dict` first. This [commonly happens when trying to grab data from parsed JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44591062).

### Error messages about string formatting

Seriously, did you *intend* to do string formatting? If you do want to format a string, [consider using f-strings or the `.format` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/) - these are easier to debug, and have fewer special cases. But more likely, the left-hand side is some string like `'1'` that should have been converted to `int` (or *maybe* `float`) first.

### Error messages about a "descriptor"

Python's error message here is fairly cryptic - it's using terminology that most programmers rarely if ever have to worry about. But once recognized, the error is very easy to pattern-match. Take special care if the class can be instantiated with no arguments - an empty pair of parentheses `()` is **still necessary** to instantiate the class; otherwise, the code refers to *the class itself*. An instance is required in order to use methods.

### Custom error messages from built-in functions

A "bad operand" for a "unary" operator (for example `bad operand type for unary +: 'str'`) [can be caused by a stray comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591385). `'a', + 'b'` is not the same as `'a' + 'b'`; it is trying to use `+` as a unary operator on the `'b'` string, and then make a tuple. (You know how you can write e.g. `-1` to get a negative number? The `-` there is a *unary operator*. It turns out you can similarly write `+1`; it means the same as `1`, of course.)

Especially if you have had to migrate code from 2.x to 3.x, be very careful about the distinction between `bytes` and `str` types in 3.x. `bytes` represents *raw data*; `str` represents *text*. These are fundamentally different and unrelated things, and it is only possible to convert from one to the other by using an *encoding*. In Python 3.x, files that are opened in a binary mode (using `'b'` in the mode string) produce `bytes` when read, and must be given something compatible with `bytes` when written to. `str` does not qualify; you must specify an encoding explicitly. The canonical for this problem is ["TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'" when handling file content in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527).

### Error messages where something "is not" usable in some way

#### Did you want to use it that way?

Python can't read your intent. For example, accessing an element of a list [is done using `[]`, not `()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735841). If the code says `()` instead, that will be interpreted as an attempt to call the list, so the error message will complain that the list is not callable.

#### Not iterable

When something `is not iterable`, the problem is very likely with the thing, rather than the iteration. If you want a `for` loop to run a specific number of times, you still need something to iterate over; a `range` is the usual choice. The same is true if you are using a list comprehension etc. to [make multiple copies of a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178). If you have an integer `x` and you want to make a *list with one item, which is that integer*, that is spelled `[x]`, not `list(x)`.

It's especially common to see `'NoneType' object is not iterable`. There is exactly one `'NoneType' object`: the special value `None` - Python forbids creating any more instances of that class. Python methods that work in-place - [especially list methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205254/) - generally return `None` rather than the list that was modified. See also [TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887381/).

#### Not callable

If a `'module' object is not callable`, it's most likely because [you want a function or class from the module, that has the same name as the module, rather than the module itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534438/). The linked example is for the `socket` standard library; other common cases include [`datetime`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44935376) and [`random`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985798).

Also make sure that the code doesn't call a function and remember the result, instead of remembering *the function itself*. This is a common problem with APIs that expect a "callback" function. (If you need to choose the arguments ahead of time, but not actually call the function, see [How can I bind arguments to a function in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277922) .) Sometimes people also [try to provide the name of a function as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20966770), rather than providing the function itself.

Beginners sometimes expect to be able to do "implicit multiplication" in a mathematical formula, the way that it works in math class. In a Python program (like other popular languages), code like `a(b + c)` **does not** multiply the integer `a` by the result of `b + c`; it attempts to call `a` as if it were a function. See [Why do I get "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable" from code like "5(side_length**2)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39800654/).

#### Not subscriptable

Sometimes, people try to get "digits" from a number by indexing into it as if it were a string. `int` and `float` values [aren't strings; they don't have digits in them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189800). So this will cause a "is not subscriptable" `TypeError`. The numeric value is the same no matter what base you write them in, and there are other ways to write a number besides base ten; so it is your responsibility to create the appropriate string first.

If you are trying to work with nested lists, be careful about indexing into them. A list like `example = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]` should be indexed like `example[i][j]`, [not e.g. `example[i[j]]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380125). The logic here should be pretty simple: the correct code means to index into `example` (getting a list of integers), and then index into that result. The incorrect code means to use `j` as an index into `i` first, because of how the brackets are nested.

If you are trying to call a function or use a class (such as the built-in `range`), remember that this uses **parentheses, not square brackets**:

```
# WRONG
range[10]
# RIGHT
range(10)
```