# i can't get this code to work and have tried a lot of things

Tags: python

this is the python code i am working on 2 hours of sleep please help me get this to work
the question for the code was to write a program to multiply all the elements of the list at even indexes.

```
def EvenProduct(arr, n):
    even = 1
    for i in range (0,n):
        if (i % 2 == 0):
            even *= arr[i]
    print("Even Index Product : " , even)

# Driver Code

arr = int(input("Enter the size of the list "))
print("\n")
num_list = list(int(num) for num in input("Enter the list items separated by space ").strip().split())[:arr]

print("User list: ", num_list)
n = len(arr)

EvenProduct(arr, n)
```

and i got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 26, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. We are not interested in the difficulty you are having with the code; we are interested in a clear **question** that emerges from your own best effort to [locate](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [understand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and demonstrate the problem (in a [mre]). Please also read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Reference: [I'm getting a TypeError. How do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73631401)

Comment: You have one line, `num_list = list(...`, doing a ton of things. It's better to break such lines up into multiple lines, so that you can debug more easily.

Comment: Not to be a noodge -- But also, a little grammar goes a long way ..  Folks will TRY to read your run-on sentence and just move to the next topic without even looking into your problem.

Comment: I am sincerely sorry, like I said it was late I will try to be better in explaining next time.

Answer (score 2):

One issue is that you read in `arr` via:

```py
arr = int(input("Enter the size of the list "))
```

But then you attempt, later, to call `len()` on `arr`:

```py
n = len(arr)
```

So, since `arr` is already an `int`, it has no length. It is a single item.

I think you meant to use `num_list` and not `arr`. If that's the case, then the last two lines of your program should be:

```
n = len(num_list)
EvenProduct(num_list, n)
```

Especially since, in `num_list`, you are referring to `arr[i]` which is invalid if `arr` is an `int`. I think you were assuming that `arr` was `num_list`, or maybe at some point you changed the name.

Answer (score 0):

You meant to write `n = len(num_list)`.

The value `arr` is an integer so, as the error indicates, it has no length.

There's no need to pass the length into the function, you can calculate it inside with `len(arr)`.

You can use the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) global function to get both index and value simultaneously.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

def evens_product(l):
    product = 1
    for i,v in enumerate(l):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            product *= v
    return product

result = evens_product([1,2,3,4,5,6])
print(result) # 15
```