# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable despite unique function name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to clean a basic dataset with Siuba, but I am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\NTDdataanalysis\venv\ntdanalysis.py", line 16, in <module>
    >> select(_.primary_uza_population == _.pop)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Here is the script itself:

```
import pandas as pd
from siuba import *
from janitor import *
from IPython.display import display

ntd_data = (
    pd.read_excel("PivotAgg.xlsm",'Sheet2', skiprows=[0,1,3,298])
    .pipe(clean_names)
    .pipe(remove_empty)
)

#print(ntd_data.columns)

(
   ntd_data
   >> select(_.primary_uza_population == _.pop)
   >> select(_.sum_of_train_revenue_miles == _.train_rev_mi)
   >> select(_.sum_of_train_miles == _.train_mi)
   >> select(_.sum_of_vehicle_passenger_car_revenue_miles == _.vehicle_rev_mi)
   >> select(_.sum_of_vehicle_passenger_car_miles == _.vehicle_mi)
)
```

From what i've found online with this error, it ocurss when the function name is confused with a class name. However, there is no class present called select.
I've tried using select without the >> notation as well (and without the paranthesis surrounding it) to no luck.

What is the issue here?

Comment: `select` is not defined here at all, therefore it must come from `from siuba import *` or from `from janitor import *`.  One of those imports (likely the second one) imports a sub-module named `select`.

Comment: What are you expecting `select` to be?  Where did you expect it to come from?

Comment: _it ocurss when the function name is confused with a class name_ No.  Functions and classes are both callable.  This is not the issue.

Comment: @JohnGordon it's close; saying "class name" here is just misspeaking. My answer clarifies this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it ocurss when the function name is confused with a class name

Not quite. Names don't get "confused", because a name can only ever mean one thing at a time. Assigning a name, such as `select`, means that it **stops** being a name for anything else, and starts being a name for whatever was assigned. Also, the error message says `'module' object is not callable`, so the problem is that the name is being used for a **module** (not a class). In fact, classes **are** callable (that's how you create objects), but modules are not.

Importing modules causes assignment to names. In particular, `import foo` means that `foo` becomes a name for some module object; `from foo import x` means that `x` becomes a name for something that was inside the `foo` module; `from foo import *` means that **any number of names** start getting used for **everything the `foo` module specifies**.

The key to understanding the problem is to notice that there **isn't** any more in the stack trace. The highlighted code is `select(_.primary_uza_population == _.pop)`; the problem is reported here; there is exactly one attempt to *call* anything; the thing we're trying to call is `select`; the error message says [there is a problem because a module is not callable; therefore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73631401/), `select` must be a module at the time that the code runs.

`janitor.functions.select` [is a module](https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor/blob/dev/janitor/functions/select.py), which [is included](https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor/blob/dev/janitor/__init__.py) in the main `janitor` package. Therefore, `from janitor import *` will make `select` **stop** meaning the [function from `siuba`](https://siuba.org/api/verb-select/), and start meaning the module from `janitor` instead.

This is the reason for the common advice not to use `from some_package import *`. That `*` might include many useful things, but it might also include many **not** useful things that actively cause a problem.